# ORA-02253: constraint specification not allowed here

Tags: sql, oracle

Hola buenas tengo esta tabla creada en *oracle*:

```
CREATE TABLE SUBCONTRACT(
CIF CHAR(9) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT PK_SUBCONTRACTS_CIF primary key,
NAME VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
ADDRESSSTREET varchar2(50) not null,
ADDRESSNUM  number(7,0) not null,
ADDRESSFLOOR varchar2(4) null,
ACCOUNTNUMBER char(24) not null,
EMAIL varchar2(50) not null,
PRICES NUMBER(10,2),
SERVICE VARCHAR(40)
);
```

Y al añadir otra para los números de teléfono:

```
CREATE TABLE SUBCONTRACTSPHONENUMBER(
CIFSUBCONTRACT CHAR(9) not null CONSTRAINT FK_SUBCONTRACTS_CIF foreign key references SUBCONTRACTS(CIF),
PHONENUMBER NUMBER(11),
CONSTRAINT PK_SUBCONTRACTSPHONENUMBER_SUBCON_PHO PRIMARY KEY (CIFSUBCONTRACT,PHONENUMBER)
);
```

Me da el error:

> ORA-02253: constraint specification not allowed here.

El número de teléfono y el *CIF* tienen que ser claves primarias y el *CIF* es *foreign* de `subcontracts`.

Un saludo.

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

No puedes declarar un *constraint* de tipo *Foreign Key* como parte de la declaración de la columna. Esto está reservado para llaves primarias, valores *default*, *check* y probablemente algún otro que si va asociados directamente a la columna.

Para declarar un a llave foránea, debes hacerlo luego de haber finalizado la declaración de la columna. De hecho, yo generalmente dejo la declaración de llaves primarias y foráneas para el final del `create table`, aunque la sintaxis no exige eso.

Traduciendo eso a código, yo dejaría tu sentencia algo como:

```
CREATE TABLE SUBCONTRACTSPHONENUMBER(
    CIFSUBCONTRACT CHAR(9) not null 
  , PHONENUMBER NUMBER(11)
  , CONSTRAINT PK_SUBCONTRACTSPHONENUMBER_SUBCON_PHO 
      PRIMARY KEY (CIFSUBCONTRACT,PHONENUMBER)
  , CONSTRAINT FK_SUBCONTRACTS_CIF 
     foreign key (CIFSUBCONTRACT) references SUBCONTRACTS(CIF)
);
```